# Proper Method for Storing JavaScript Instances in Nan::ObjectWrap C++ Class

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

Let's say I have two classes that are developed in C++, but are exposed using Nan NodeJS native modules. For example, a "Sprite" and "Texture" class.

In the JavaScript, I want to be able to have a Sprite store a Texture as if it were just another property:

```
// Local instance of texture
var t = new Texture();

// Global instances of Sprites that won't be GC'd
global.spr = new Sprite();
global.spr2 = new Sprite();

// Same texture can be assigned to multiple sprites
spr.texture = t;
spr2.texture = t;

console.log(spr.texture);
```

On the C++ side of things, the "texture" property of the Sprite would be a Getter/Setter that stores or retrieves the Texture. The question is though, what would be the proper way to store an instance of Texture internally (from the provided v8::Local)? Like, what do I need to do to register it as "owned" by the  Sprite and cause it not to get GC'd as it probably would be in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `Persistent` handle as a member of your Sprite class that stores the Texture instance. The Sprite destructor needs to reset the the handle to avoid a leak.

```
class Sprite : public Nan::ObjectWrap {
public:
  Nan::Persistent<v8::Object> textureHandle;

  static NAN_SETTER(SetTexture) {
    Sprite* sprite = Nan::ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Sprite>(info.This());
    if (Nan::New(Texture::constructor)->HasInstance(value)) {
      sprite->textureHandle.Reset(value);
    } else {
      // value wasn't a Texture instance; do something
    }
  }

  static NAN_GETTER(GetTexture) {
    Sprite* sprite = Nan::ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Sprite>(info.This());
    Isolate* iso = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    if (sprite->textureHandle.IsEmpty()) {
      // Texture hasn't been set yet; do something
    } else {
      info.GetReturnValue().Set(sprite->TextureHandle.Get(iso));
    }
  }

  ~Sprite() {
    textureHandle.Reset();
  }
}
```

(Not shown: the initialization code to register the getter/setter.)